# Store javascript array as a csv-file on server

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, save

I need to persist the data of a 2-dimensional javascript array on a server.
Since I already implemented a function to retrieve data from a csv-file which is already placed on a server, i was wondering if it is possible to store javascript-arrays as csv-files on the server?

If there is another way to store javascript array-data permanently and use it/manipulate it on demand, I would also be very interested.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Javascript runs at the client-side (unless you are talking about NodeJS), at the web browser. So, you have to submit the data from the client-side to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can JSON serialize the array on the Javascript side and send to the server using AJAX, where you'd unserialize it and add it to the CSV file.

You can also use any database to store that data.

Comment: I have to work within a process management tool called Polarion ALM, which is honestly not really a tool which I would reccommend^^. So my options are quite limited and I am afraid that I do not have direct access to a database.

But I'll try my luck with Json and AJAX tomorrow in work.
I guess you don't have a code snippet I could start with?

Thank you for your quick response.